# Read a random word from a file for user to guess - Java

Tags: java

I'm write a code that pulls a word from a file and guesses it. For instance the word would be "apple".

The user will see: *****

If they input 'p' as a guess they see: *pp**

So far it's working if I manually the word apple in a variable called secretPhrase, however I'm not sure how to have the program pull the word from a text file and store it into secretPhrase for the user to guess.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String secretPhrase = "apple";
    String guesses = " ";
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean notDone = true;

    Scanner word = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a word: ");



    while(true) {

        notDone = false;
        for(char secretLetter : secretPhrase.toCharArray()) { 
            if(guesses.indexOf(secretLetter) == -1) { 
                System.out.print('*');
                notDone = true;
            } else {
                System.out.print(secretLetter);
            }
        }
        if(!notDone) {
            break;
        }

        System.out.print("\nEnter your letter:");
        String letter = keyboard.next();
        guesses += letter;
    }
    System.out.println("Congrats");
}
```

Comment: create a text file with all the words, maybe one per line. then read all the content, for example into a random list. then pick a random index of that list, done. if the file is huge (gigabytes), might want to use RandomAccessFile instead to find a random line without reading everything.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.  One is to do the following.  It is not complete and doesn't check on border cases.  But you can figure that out. It presumes the file contains one word per line.

```
        try {
            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(
                    new File("wordfile.txt"), "r");
            Random r = new Random();
            // ensure the length is an int
            int len = (int)(raf.length()&0x7FFFFFFF);
            // randomly select a location
            long loc = r.nextInt(len);
            // go to that file location
            raf.seek(loc);
            // find start of next line
            byte c = raf.readByte();
            while((char)c != '\n') {
                c = raf.readByte();
            }
            // read the line
            String line = raf.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

A much easier solution for perhaps a smaller set of words is to just read them into a `List<String>` and the do a `Collections.shuffle()` to randomize them.  Then just use them in the shuffled order.